# replace text within parentheses with string in table column using set regexp_replace (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to replace the text within parentheses and the parentheses with string in table column using set regexp_replace

e.g. "Apartment (H B)" to be "Rental"

I have tried the following but did not work any idea what to do?

```
UPDATE prime_location
    SET Type = 
        regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(Type,')',' '),
                '(',' '), 'Apartment H B ', 'Rental')
WHERE Type IN ('(',')','Apartment H B');
```

I need to use the set regexp_replace

Thanks

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution using the REPLACE() function

```
UPDATE prime_location
    SET Type = REPLACE(Type, "Apartment (H B)", "Rental")
```